# How to read matrix from file in octave?

Tags: octave

I am trying to read a matrix from file in Octave but I just can't find a solution.
The input file is:

```
4
1 4 2 3
1 4 2 1
4 2 1 4
1 2 1 3
```

where 4 is the number of rows and columns. I want to be able to store that information in a matrix and to be able to use it's elements by calling them like `a(2,3)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function [`dlmread()`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/dlmread.html):

> `data = dlmread(file, sep, r0, c0)`
>
> Read the matrix data from a text file which uses the delimiter `sep` between data values.
>
> If `sep` is not defined the separator between fields is determined from the file itself.
>
> Given two scalar arguments `r0` and `c0`, these define the starting row and column of the data to be read. These values are indexed from zero, such that the first row corresponds to an index of zero.

So you can simply use the one-liner:

```
data = dlmread('input_file', ' ', 1, 0);
```

By calling the function with `r0` set to `1`, you're effectively skipping the first line, which contains the (now useless) number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

just type load + space + file name like

```
load fileName.txt
data = fileName;
data(2,3)
```

or

`data = load('fileName.txt');`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read in all the data using [`fscanf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Formatted-Input.html#XREFfscanf). Then you can extract the first value to get the number of rows and columns and then reshape the remainder of the data into the expected size.

```
fid = fopen('data.dat', 'r');
data = fscanf(fid, '%f');
nRows = data(1);

data = reshape(data(2:end), nRows, nRows).';

%// 1  4  2  3
%// 1  4  2  1
%// 4  2  1  4
%// 1  2  1  3
```

You can then index into the result just like you would with any array

```
data(2,3)
%// 2
```

Comment: why do you want to open the file in binary mode (fopen ... 'rb')?

Comment: @Andy Just habit, really. When using `fscanf` or related functions, the performance is the same regardless of the second input to `fopen`.

Comment: well, at least the second param to fopen is important if you want to write or append to the file ;-)

Comment: @Andy True! I've updated it in the answer to avoid possible confusion.